# Why can't I see the output of another executable in an invoked ScriptBlock?

Tags: powershell

I am creating and invoking PowerShell ScriptBlock objects. I noticed that when the ScriptBlock includes another executable, I am not able to see the output from that process. Keyboard input is still accepted though.

Here is a simplified version of the problem. In this case, I do not see any output from cmd.exe but I can type 'exit{ENTER}' and return to PowerShell

`function Test-CMD {cmd.exe}`

`$sb = [System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock]::Create('Test-CMD')`

`$sb.Invoke()`

Is there a way to get the executable output to the console? Other ScriptBlock output works as expected.

Comment: Use the call `&` operator in place of `Invoke()`: `& $sb`

Comment: As an aside: There's a [type accelerator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Type_Accelerators) for script blocks: `[scriptblock]` is short for `[System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerShell is blocked until the method (`$sb.Invoke()`) returns - to avoid this, use the `&` call operator instead:

```
function Test-CMD {cmd.exe}

$sb = [System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock]::Create('Test-CMD')

& $sb
```